Variable expansion in "Run" command in docker
Example 1:-
FROM ubuntu:latest
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo "export MY_VARIABLE=my_value" >> ~/.profile
RUN cat ~/.profile
RUN "source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE"

sudo docker build --no-cache -t hello-image --progress plain  .
o/p:-
variable4:my_value

Example 2:-
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN echo "export MY_VARIABLE=my_value" >> ~/.profile
RUN cat ~/.profile
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE"

sudo docker build --no-cache -t hello-image --progress plain  .
o/p:-
variable4:

Why in first example, "$MY_VARIABLE" got value "my_value" but in second example it is empty string?

If you RUN echo ~/.profile, is it the same filename in both cases?  In any case containers don't usually have "home directories", most paths to running container commands don't read shell dotfiles, and source isn't a standard shell command; can you use ENV to set the variable rather than depending on ~/.profile?

Your scripts are both missing a " off the end of the 4th line and would echo the string env which doesn't appear in the output you show for them so the scripts you're asking for help with cannot be the scripts you're showing us and so we can't reliably help you diagnose the problem. Please make sure to post examples that we can copy/paste to reproduce your problem.

That was a typo error. I have corrected it and added missing ". Thanks

RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE"

When a run, entrypoint, or cmd is not in the exec format (a JSON array), the contents are passed to the a shell to execute. So the above is run as:
/bin/sh -c "/bin/bash -c \"source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE\""

In that scenario, $MY_VARIABLE is expanded by the first /bin/sh, and then bash is run to source the profile and print the echo without any variable (since it has already been expanded).
An alternative way to write this that only runs /bin/bash without an added shell is:
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE" ]


Thanks for the response. But in first example we have,
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
...
RUN "source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE"
So here "RUN" will be converted to
/bin/bash -c "source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE"
So according to your answer, bash shell should first expand "$MY_VARIABLE" which will result into empty string. Then it will source the .profile file. So "$MY_VARIABLE" should be empty string. But it is not the case. I get value of it as "my_value". Why there is difference between first and second example? Am I missing something here.?

Both Dockerfiles have a SHELL defined. The second is just an implicit definition, when you don't specify a SHELL, the default value is SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]. The difference is adding a second shell in the RUN.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#shell

Thnanks. So in first example , /bin/bash -c "source ~/.profile && echo env variable4: $MY_VARIABLE"
The bash shell will not expand $MY_Variable before executing "source" just like "sh" shell  did in case of second example?
